# Get previous Sunday Date object

Tags: android, datetime, android-calendar

```
Calendar cal =Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.SUNDAY);
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
            date = cal.getTime();
            myDate = sdf.format(date);
```

If I use the above code, on one phone I'm getting previous Sunday, which is correct, but on another phone, I'm getting the the date of the next Sunday. How do I get previous Sunday on all phones, is there any other way to retrieve it? I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Calendar cal =Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,-(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)));
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
date = cal.getTime();
myDate = sdf.format(date);
```

You can use this